# How to understand a recursive inorder traversal of a BST in Java?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I am trying to understand how the well-established methods of implementing an inorder traversal of a binary search tree are functioning in Java.

I am given the following code:

```
public void inorder() {
       if (!this.isEmpty()) {
           this.getLeft().inorder();
           System.out.print(this.getValue());
           this.getRight().inorder();
       }
   }
```

with `isEmpty()` returning whether the current Node is `null`, `getValue()` returning the value of the current node, and `getLeft()` as well as `getRight()` respectively returning the left and right successor node.

My problem here is, I do not understand how one is able to process the traversal with this code. I have visualized my chain of thoughts on a sheet of paper for you guys to see, with the circles being the nodes, the black squares being null nodes, and the encircled node being the current (this) object. As I am following the pseudocode, I would land in a null node at the end and hit the recursive dead-end case. I also do not at all understand how the code is able to go back in the tree hierarchy once we've already set subtree nodes as the current this object.

[My visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3o1P.jpg)

Am I imagining this wrong, and if so, could someone help me understand the right way of doing this? The code works, but I really need to understand how that comes through. Any help would be super super appreciated

Comment: What do you think happens after the call is made on the "null" node?

Comment: My perception is that the method just ends altogether because we only get into the if-case when the current node is not null...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As I am following the pseudocode, I would land in a null node at the end and hit the recursive dead-end case

When you reach the "dead-end" case, this means the current branch of the recursion tree ends. It doesn't mean the entire recursion ends.

After all, when method X calls method Y, and method Y ends, the control returns to method X. This remains true when methods X and Y have the same name. The recursion only ends after the original `inorder()` call (which was executed on the root of the tree) returns.

You can number each call to the `inorder()` method in order to tell them apart:

```
1. root.inorder() calls
    2. root.getLeft().inorder() calls
        3. root.getLeft().getLeft().inorder() calls
            4. root.getLeft().getLeft().getLeft().inorder()
               this node is empty, so inorder() #4 method returns control to the previous one (#3)
           now #3 call prints the current node via System.out.print(this.getValue())
             which prints the left most node of the tree 
           then #3 calls 
            5. root.getLeft().getLeft().getRight().inorder()
               this node is also empty, so the current inorder() method returns control to #3
           now #3 also ends, and returns control to the previous method (#2)
```

and so on...

Comment: thanks Eran, that's the crucial point I missed.... cheers!!!